# Alternate credentials - how to generate list

Tags: azure-devops

I'm looking on a way to list alternate credentials created by users in my Azure DevOps organization as we are thinking about shutting this feature down.

Comment: Could you please describe more details about your scenario?

Comment: Microsoft will shut down this feature soon https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/azure-devops-will-no-longer-support-alternate-credentials-authentication/

Answer (score 0):

> I'm looking on a way to list alternate credentials created by users in my Azure DevOps organization

Sorry for any inconvenience.

I am afraid there is no such a way to list all the alternate credentials created by users in your Azure DevOps organization. This behavior is by designed.

That because the alternate credentials are created based on **each user's account**. And as we know the security level of the alternate credentials is Least secure:

[image]

MS don't recommend using alternate credentials. So, MS does not provide a method to collect alternate credentials. You can notify all users in your Azure DevOps organization that you are thinking about shutting this feature down.

Hope this helps.